# Scikit learn fit estimator with predefined number of classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

So, I need to use some of the estimators in scikit-learn, namely LogisticRegression and SVM, but I have a problem, I have an extremely unbalanced dataset and need to run Kfold cross validation. The thing is sometimes the fold I am fitting can have only one target class of the available ones. I wanted to know if there's any way with these estimators to predefine the number of classes, maybe something like passing them a one-hot encoding representations of the target where it doesn't matter if all the examples are from one class, the shape of the target matrix will define the number of classes already.

Is there any way to do this with scikit-learn? Maybe with another library? I know those two algorithms use liblinear, maybe there's some interface I can use in that case.

Any way, thank you for your time.

EDIT: StratifiedFold cross validation is not useful for me because sometimes I have less amount of occurrences than the number of folds. E.g. it can happen that I have a dataset with 50 instances and 3 classes, but 46 can be of one class, 2 of a second class and 2 of a third class and though I can go for 3 fold cross validation I would generally need results of more folds than that, plus even with 3 folds still leaves open the case where one class is the only available for one fold.

Comment: Please be more precise. I don't understand your this question. Normally people use [Stratified folds in these cases](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html).

Comment: There's an edition added to the original question. Stratified folds is not useful to me in my particular scenario.

Comment: The problem is not in a library but with your problem setting. If you have one class in a fold **there is nothing to learn** (when the task is regular classification), so it is ill posed problem. Gather more data, redefine testing (kfold does not apply) or look into different paradigms of learning. If you don't care and just want to force the library to work- just detect when set of labels is a singleton and put all the predictions equal to this label, since this is the only valid model for such dsta.

Answer (score 0):

The comment that said you need to gather more data may be right. However if you believe you have enough data for your model to learn something useful, you can over sample your minority classes (or possibly under sample the majority classes, but this sounds like a problem for over sampling). Having only one class in the data set makes it pretty much impossible for your model to learn anything about that class.

Here are some links to over sampling and under sampling libraries in python. The famous imbalanced-learn library is great.

https://imbalanced-learn.org/en/stable/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler.html

https://imbalanced-learn.org/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.RandomOverSampler.html

https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html

https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/auto_examples/over-sampling/plot_comparison_over_sampling.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-over-sampling-plot-comparison-over-sampling-py

https://imbalanced-learn.org/en/stable/combine.html

Your case sounds like a good candidate for SMOTE. You also mentioned you wanted to change the ratio. There is a parameter in imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE called ratio, where you would pass a dictionary. You can also do it with percentages (see the documentation).

SMOTE uses the K-Nearest-Neighbors algorithm to make "similar" data points to those under sampled ones. This is a more powerful algorithm than traditional over-sampling because then when your model gets the training data it helps avoid the issue where your model is memorizing key points of specific examples. Instead, smote creates a "similar" data point (likely in a multi-dimensional space) so your model can learn to generalize better.

**NOTE: It is vital that you do not use SMOTE on the full data set. You MUST use SMOTE on the training set only (i.e. after you split), and then validate on the validation set and test sets to see if your SMOTE model out performed your other model(s). If you do not do this, there will be data leakage and you will get a model that doesn't even closely resemble what you want.**

```
from collections import Counter
from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
import numpy as np
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)
sm = SMOTE(random_state=0, n_jobs=8, ratio={'class1':100, 'class2':100, 'class3':80, 'class4':60, 'class5':90})
X_resampled, y_resampled = sm.fit_sample(X_normalized, y)

print('Original dataset shape:', Counter(y))
print('Resampled dataset shape:', Counter(y_resampled))

X_train_smote, X_test_smote, y_train_smote, y_test_smote = train_test_split(X_resampled, y_resampled)
X_train_smote.shape, X_test_smote.shape, y_train_smote.shape, y_test_smote.shape, X_resampled.shape, y_resampled.shape

smote_xgbc = XGBClassifier(n_jobs=8).fit(X_train_smote, y_train_smote)

print('TRAIN')
print(accuracy_score(smote_xgbc.predict(np.array(X_train_normalized)), y_train))
print(f1_score(smote_xgbc.predict(np.array(X_train_normalized)), y_train))

print('TEST')
print(accuracy_score(smote_xgbc.predict(np.array(X_test_normalized)), y_test))
print(f1_score(smote_xgbc.predict(np.array(X_test_normalized)), y_test))
```